# Use Caffeine cache in Spark-streaming

Tags: apache-spark, caching, spark-streaming, caffeine

I'm using [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine)'s `AsyncLoadingCache` to cache lookup data from a database.

Now I'd like to integrate this into Spark Streaming. My idea is to let each worker maintain such a cache with a given refresh rate. But how to do that?

Is it better to define it as a broadcast variable and at each timeout recreate it and spread among the workers?

What is the best practice here?